# How to split output with \n properly in python?

Tags: python, printing

In python3 I am using `subprocess.check_output` to get the output from a command, but when I print it it looks something like

```
b'first line\nsecond line\nthird line'
```

How can I easily 'convert' that to something like the following:

```
first line
second line
third line
```

I tried the following code:

```
for line in output.split(b'\n'):
    print(line)
```

but got the following output:

```
b'first line'
b'second line'
b'third line'
```

How to do it correct (and probably in one short line)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), the output from `check_output` is:

> By default, this function will return the data as encoded bytes. The actual encoding of the output data may depend on the command being invoked, so the decoding to text will often need to be handled at the application level.

So, to convert from `bytes` to `str` you need to use the `decode` function like so:

```
print(x.decode("utf-8") )
```